# mysqldump.exe requires a password even though it is given in the argument

Tags: c#, mysql, process

The question says it all - I'm creating a `Process` and I'm passing a `ProcessStartInfo` object with the `ProcessStartInfo.fileName` and `ProcessStartInfo.Arguments` as constructor parameters to this process.

As `ProcessStartInfo.fileName` I'm using mysql.exe which is already contained in my project folder.

My `ProcessStartInfo.Arguments` string looks like this;

```
-h localhost --port=3306 -u pete -p 1234 db1 -r C:\\Users\\Pete\\Databases\\localhost_db1.sql
```

When I start the process the console asks for a password to enter - problem is that I don't want reenter it. The authentication and the dump should both be executed in one step - is that possible?

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise with the .NETCoreApp 1.1 framework.

EDIT:
When I'm not using a password, everything works fine. The .sql-File is created
and the database was successfully dumped.

Comment: Try removing the space between the -p and the password.

Comment: Oh god - didn't think that it would be that easy.. Thanks! 
I still get a warning displayed which tells me that putting the password in the argument line is insecure - but in the end it doesn't even matter - at least for my project ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When programming a application that uses a dataset such as MySQL or Mongodb you never want to store a password in plain text. You should either put a textbox thats hidden to hide the password from catching eyes, or use a file inside of the project when it is compiled to hold the password instead.

When you use "-p" parameter it will assume you want to enter the password its the same with "-u". Try using --username and --password instead to set the username and password to connect with.

Comment: Yeah , I'll do it right like you recommended - at the moment I'm just experimenting a little. And thanks for the advice, I'll use that in my argument!

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be a space between the -p and the actually password so try removing it such as'

> -p1234

Of course putting the password like this might not be the most secure option!